# Converter arquivos em sub-pastas - Python

Tags: python, script

Tenho um script que baixa as pastas do Sharepoint todo mês e transforma todos os arquivos de cada sub-pasta de .xls para .html, segue o pedaço da conversão:

```
import sys
import os
folder = r'C:\Users\prmatteo\xxxx\Área de Trabalho\POWER AUTOMATE\ANP Sharepoint'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
       infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
       if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
       oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
       newname = infilename.replace('.html', '.xls')
       output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente, porém, todo mês, eu tenho que ficar
selecionando cada sub-pasta por vez, referente a sub-pasta daquele mês. EX: (C:\Users\xxx\xxx\POWER AUTOMATE\ANP Sharepoint\ANP\202207), que é referente à Julho, para converter esses arquivos.

Gostaria de saber se tem como converter todos os arquivos, dentro das sub-pastas, automaticamente, toda vez que baixar uma nova pasta dentro dessa pasta raíz, referente àquele mês.

Comment: Pedro, o site possuí algumas **regras** e **padrões** para realizar uma pergunta, sugiro a leitura do [Manual de como não fazer uma pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1)

Answer (score 1):

Se você considerar um diretório como:

```
files/
├── A/
│   └── 1.txt
├── B/
│   └── C/
│       └── 2.csv
└── D/
    └── E/
        └── F/
            └── 3.pdf
```

Você pode fazer:

```py
import glob


for file in glob.glob('files/**/*.*', recursive=True):
  print(file)

# files/A/1.txt
# files/B/C/2.csv
# files/D/E/F/3.pdf
```

Ou

```py
from pathlib import Path


path = Path('files')

for file in path.rglob('*.*'):
  print(file)

# files/A/1.txt
# files/B/C/2.csv
# files/D/E/F/3.pdf
```

Assim conseguirá listar todos os arquivos de forma recursiva e processá-los de uma vez.